# Hive external table (parquet) column is not visible

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet

All fields are queryable except `product_price`. The column is present in table's column list. Querying yields this strange error:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Group type [message schema {
  optional binary product_name (UTF8);
  optional binary product_category (UTF8);
  optional double product_price;
  optional binary purchase_date (UTF8);
  optional binary client_ip_address (UTF8);
  optional binary pdate;
}
] does not contain requested field: optional double product_price
```

Table is a partitioned table stored in `parquet` format.
`SHOW CREATE TABLE PURCHASES`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `purchases`(  
  `product_name` string,    
  `product_category` string,    
  `product_price` double,   
  `purchase_date` string,   
  `client_ip_address` string)   
PARTITIONED BY (    
  `pdate` string)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'     
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'   
OUTPUTFORMAT    
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'  
LOCATION    
  'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/data'    
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1532388930')
```

Imporant notice: when using `STRING` instead of `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL`, it works just fine.

Comment: Are you able to give us a `show create table` ?

Comment: @rahoogan Of course, added in the description.

Answer (score 0):

As you would know, when using external tables, the `create table` statement only creates the metadata for the table. Everytime the table is referenced in a subsequent query, hive will attempt to parse the data into the requested types.

Since your query works when you use a `string` type for the column, and not when using `double` - I would wager that your source data contains some records in that column which cannot be cast as a `double`.

I would do a profile of the data first to understand if there are any anomalies, and filter them out.

Comment: I generate the parquet files from pandas `DataFrame`. In the frame structure corresponding column has type `float64`, if I generate it as a `double`. Numbers for the column are chosen at random in range from 25 to 75.

Comment: Ok, you may lose some precision converting from float64 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362996/hive-double-precision), and decimal has a maximum precision of 38 bits. But that's a separate issue. Can you try generating the table with string, and then casting to double in your select?

Comment: This definitely works, but I wanted to know about the cause of this strange exception.